# Functors from the category of subobjects of a group $G$

Tags: category-theory

Consider $Set_{f}$ the category of finite sets and functions and let $G$ be a finite group.

We can define the category $Fun(G,Set_f)$ of functors, that, is objects are finite sets with group actions and morphisms equivariant functions.

I would like to assemble all the group action of all the subgroups $H\leq G$. That is, i want a category which has

- an object is a pair $(X,\phi)$ where $X$ is a finite set and $\phi:H\longrightarrow Bij(X)$ a group homomorphism from some subgroup $H\leq G$,
- a morphism $(X,\phi)\longrightarrow (Y,\psi)$ is a function of the underlying sets such that it is equivariant with respect the actions (possibly $\psi:H^{\prime}\longrightarrow Bij(Y)$ with $H\leq H^{\prime}$)

Is that the category of functors $Fun(Sub(G),Set_f)$ where $Sub(G)$ is the category of subojects of $G$ ?

If not, could someone explain what would be a functor $Sub(G)\longrightarrow Set_f$

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what is a functor $Sub(G)\to Set_f$, because it's not clear what the category of subgroups of $G$ is. Is it the subcategory of groups formed by the subgroups of $G$? The poset of sugbroups seen as a thin category?

Comment: Probably i mean the poset of subgroups...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, no, that is not what that functor category is.  $\mathsf{Sub}(G)$ is just a partially ordered set (poset) which can be viewed as a category, and any poset with the same structure would be equivalent.  The fact that you labelled the elements of this poset with groups is irrelevant.  A functor $F : \mathsf{Sub}(G) \to \mathbf{Set}_f$ is a collection of finite sets, one per subobject of $G$, with a function $F(H_1)\to F(H_2)$ whenever $H_1 \leq H_2$.  The only equations that would need to be satisfied by these functions is if $A \leq X \leq B$ and $A \leq Y \leq B$ then $F(A) \to F(X) \to F(B)$ is the same function as $F(A)\to F(Y)\to F(B)$.

Two equivalent ways of organizing the your data are: [indexed categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indexed+category) and [fibered categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration). For the indexed category perspective, let $\mathbf{Grp}$ the category of groups and $\iota : \mathbf{Grp}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ be the functor viewing each group as a one-object category. Write $\mathcal{D}^\mathcal{C}$ for the functor category from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. The (pseudo)functor $\mathbf{Set}_f^{\iota(-)} : \mathbf{Grp}^{op} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ gives you an indexed category.  You can now restrict this (pseudo)functor to the (not full) subcategory of $\mathbf{Grp}$ consisting of $G$ and its subobjects to get an indexed category corresponding to what you desire.

Alternatively, consider the category whose objects are pairs $(G, F_G)$ where $G$ is a group and $F_G : \iota G \to \mathbf{Set}_f$, and whose arrows $(f,\alpha) : (H,F_H) \to (G,F_G)$ consist of a group homomorphism $f : H \to G$ and a natural transformation $\alpha : F_H \to F_G \circ \iota(f)$.  There is a projection $\pi(G,F_G) = G$ that takes this category to $\mathbf{Grp}$ and makes this a fibered category. (Indeed, this is just the [Grothendieck construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction) applied to the indexed category above.)  You can then change the base of the fibration to be the subcategory of $\mathbf{Grp}$ consisting of $G$ and its subobjects to get a fibered category over the subgroups.  The total category of the resulting fibration will be exactly the category you describe.